# Maven groupId for a URL with tilde

Tags: java, maven, url

How will a Maven `groupId` for a URL such as

```
site.com/~myname/projectname
```

be formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groupId doesn't have to be based on a domain (or url in this case). The id is used to construct the local directory path, so you can't just use a full url.

A common practice is to create the id in the same way as a java package name. This is not required though, you can also just use a single word if you like.

I would suggest `com.site.myname.projectname`, or `com.myname.projectname`, depending on your association with the site. Even if this is based on domain names, you don't need to own the domain according to the java package naming guidelines. You should just make sure to choose something reasonably unique.

If you just want to refer users to your site, you can add it in an [`<url>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#More_Project_Information) element.

From the [Maven POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates):

> **groupId:** This is generally unique amongst an organization or a project. For example, all core Maven artifacts do (well, should) live under the groupId org.apache.maven. Group ID's do not necessarily use the dot notation, for example, the junit project. Note that the dot-notated groupId does not have to correspond to the package structure that the project contains. It is, however, a good practice to follow. When stored within a repository, the group acts much like the Java packaging structure does in an operating system. The dots are replaced by OS specific directory separators (such as '/' in Unix) which becomes a relative directory structure from the base repository. In the example given, the org.codehaus.mojo group lives within the directory $M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo.